# Почему не считает байты? Выдает ошибку AccessControlException

Tags: java, input

```
import java.io.*;

class FilelnputStream { 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { 
     int size; 
     InputStream f1 = new FileInputStream("Hello");
     size = f1.available(); 
     System.out.println("Total Available Bytes: " + size); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы посчитать количество байт в слове достаточно вызвать метод

```
int size = "Hello".getBytes().length
```

Для того чтобы узнать размер файла лучше возпользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```
int size = Files.size(Paths.get("/my_directory/my_file.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас нет доступа до файла. Ошибка это прекрасно сообщает.

Ошибка сгенерирована в рамках выполнения [конструктора](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream(java.lang.String))

Через дебагер или StackTrace вы можете увидеть, что доступ к файлу запрещен. Это вам сообщит `java.lang.SecurityManager`

**UPD**
Если вы ходите посчитать количество байт файла, то можете указать абсолютный 
 путь до него, если не уверены какой будет относительный, например, так

```
 InputStream f1 = new FileInputStream("C://file.txt");
```

Если вам нужно посчитать количество байт в слове, то можно либо взять его длину, либо вот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4385623/9719337) на англиской версии данной сайта

Comment: Ну то что запрещен, это понятно. Как тогда сделать чтобы метод посчитал байты "Hello" и также если я вставлю ссылку на файл, например "/C:/file.txt" ?

Comment: Вам нужно посчитать байты слова или файла?

Comment: Для начала слова. Ну и файла, как пример посмотреть.

Comment: @AlexeyVL, FileInputStream принимает путь до файла. Для получения байтов строки есть метод getBytes()

Comment: @Dred, не понимаю к чему ваш комментарий, все то, что вы написали, я не отрицал :)